# Adding a return value to an object

Tags: javascript, object

I am wanting to add the return value of a dropdown to an object I have created with placeholders.

```
pinecones.onchange = function(e) {
  let value = pinecones.options[pinecones.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

Instead of console logging the return value, I want to add it to this object:

```
let stack = {
pinecones: null,
kindling: null,
logs: null
};
```

Comment: In what way do you want to add it to the object? As a value (for which key?) or a key (with what value?)

Comment: Thanks Nick :) as a value for the pinecones key.

Comment: `stack.pinecones = value`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to add another key/value pair to your object (stack variable).

This would be my fix:

```
pinecones.onchange = function(e) {
    let value = pinecones.options[pinecones.selectedIndex].value;
    stack.value = value; // the key name can be something else
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the `change` event with `e.target.value`.

```js
const pineconesSelectEl = document.querySelector('select')

let stack = {
  pinecones: null,
  kindling: null,
  logs: null
};

pineconesSelectEl.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target
  stack.pinecones = value
  console.log(stack);
})
```

```html
<label>pinecones: 
  <select>
    <option value="">Select pinecones</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

We can make our solution a little more re-usable by adding our change event listener to all select elements, and getting both the `name` and `value` from the change event's `target`.

```js
const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select')

let stack = {
  pinecones: null,
  kindling: null,
  logs: null
};

selectEls.forEach(selectEl => {
  selectEl.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const {value, name} = e.target
    stack[name] = value
    console.log(stack);
  })
})
```

```html
<label>pinecones: 
  <select name="pinecones">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>kindling: 
  <select name="kindling">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>logs: 
  <select name="logs">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</label>
```